# How to loop thru each row in the data-file in Postman Collection Runner & then output into file

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have a Postman test that executes a query based on the ID from that data-file (.csv), and supposed to return the "Name" (in the response). This data-file contains multiple entries. But the dilemma I have as following (I have 2 questions):
1. How can I have my test to loop thru each row, and execute the query for each of the values/rows in the data-file?
2. How can I output the needed value (in my case the "Name" only, and not the whole Response) into an output file?

Here is the Postman query:
`[GET]  http://myurl.com/company({{COMPANY_ID}})`

Here is the test portion of this call:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
console.log(jsonData.Name)
```

Here is an example of the .CSV data-file:

```
COMPANY_ID, COMPANY_LOCATION
2335, Alaska
4567, Mexico
6789, Hawaii
...
```

Here is the output I expect:

```
Company1
MyCompany
Company2
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer for question No1: 
You can use the Postman Runner or Newman for using your CSV datafile.
[image]

You can access your data row by row by using `data["<ColumnName>"]` in your Test- or pre-request-script.
In your case `data["COMPANY_ID"]` and `data["COMPANY_LOCATION"]`

Take a look here for further informations: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/collection_runs/working_with_data_files/

Answer for question No2:
Unfortunately it is not possible to store date in files from PostMan without hacking. You can write your data into a global variable and export them later.
An other option is to write your file over an other WebAPI service like DropBox.

Comment: Thanks @DieGraueEminenz that is what I needed.